# Java Design: How to expose and encapsulate a vendor API?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I know basic Java, but I struggle sometimes with object orientation design.

There is a vendor api I use, and I wanted to wrap it to be reusable as a `lib` in other projects.
All the services from the vendor are different classes and have no hierarchy and so on, but I have no option to change it.
So I want to use composition and ensure I don't repeat myself.

I thought initially to create a service that would receive the parameters that are common to all services, and this service would implement the api.

I tried refactoring this code here and there, and I'm pretty sure this design I'm trying has some great problems as I noticed when trying to create unit tests :)

How could I achieve a better design?
Code as of now:

```
/* This is how I call the service from the vendor today */
class VendorConsumer {
    void exampleCake() {
        VendorServiceCake vendorServiceCake = new VendorServiceCake();
        VendorApiCake cakeApi = a.getCakeApi(1234);
        cakeApi.authenticate("user", "password");
        cakeApi.cookDeliciousCake(CakeIngredients ingredients);
    }

    void exampleSellPie() {
        VendorServiceSellPie vendorServiceSellPie = new VendorServiceSellPie();
        VendorApiSellPie apiSellPie = a.getPieApi(1234); //same parameters as above
        apiSellPie.authenticate("user", "password"); //same parameters as above
        apiSellPie.sellDeliciousPie(List<Customer> customer);
    }
}

// ---------------------------------------------
/* Below is what I'm trying to do */
class UsageTest {
//    This is how users of my .jar would call it
    void usage() {
        BakeryService service = new BakeryServiceCake("user", "password", 1234);
        List<Cake> cakeList = service.cookDeliciousCake(CakeIngredients ingrediets);
    }
    void usage2() {
        BakeryService service = new BakeryServiceSellPie("user", "password", 1234);
        List<Payments> payments = service.sellDeliciousPie(List<Customer> customer);
    }
}

class BakeryService { //is this class useless?
    public BakeryService(String user, String pass, int parameterNeeded) {
    }
    private void checkParameters() {
        //do some checkings of the parameters
    }
}

class BakeryServiceCake extends BakeryService implements KitchenCakeApi {
    KitchenCakeApi api;
    public BakeryServiceCake(String user, String pass, int parameterNeeded) {
        super(user, pass, parameterNeeded);
        this.api = new KitchenCakeApiImpl(user, pass, parameterNeeded)
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticate() {
        api.authenticate();
    }

    @Override
    public void cookDeliciousCake(CakeIngredients ingredients) {
        api.cookDeliciousCake(ingredients);
    }
}

interface KitchenCakeApi {
    void authenticate();
    void cookDeliciousCake(CakeIngredients ingredients);
}

class KitchenCakeApiImpl implements KitchenCakeApi {

    private VendorServiceCake vendorServiceCake;
    private VendorApiCake cakeApi;

    public KitchenCakeApiImpl(String user, String pass, int parameterNeeded) {
        vendorServiceCake = new VendorServiceCake();
        cakeApi = a.getCakeApi(parameterNeeded); // that 1234
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticate() {
        cakeApi.authenticate("user", "password");
    }

    @Override
    public void cookDeliciousCake(CakeIngredients ingredients) {
        cakeApi.cookDeliciousCake(CakeIngredients ingredients);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Some thoughts: a) SO is not a codereview site (codereview.stackexchange.com is one) B) you are talking about interfaces, but all I see is classes. The core thing here is: an interface should not be a concrete class, it should be an interface. C) beyond that: you do not **new** for business logic objects, you absolutely have to use dependency injection to get such objects into your classes, or you making testing almost impossible. Long story short: watch https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79 ... all of them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questioner asks for code review-like feedback.

Comment: thanks for the feedback on this @GhostCat. I agree I should post this in codereview then.. sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

The API's generally have some hierarchy/structure to it but you will need a keen eye to observe it, let's just say Java File handling is based on decorator pattern that too almost exact text book implementation.

Hard to answer without seeing the vendor API.
Probable Approach -

1. Use Adapter pattern help to encapsulates you from third party API.
   Adapter has a cost to it which is lots of code to write but maintenance is easier.
2. If Adapters explode use it with proxy pattern to make a life bit easier.
3. Facade can help you in case of complex operations but this could be just an add-on in your case.

**Two cents** - http://www.oodesign.com/ go through design patterns just as an overview and see the problem it solves if it rings a bell go deeper else move on.

Happy designing.